# Why are row vectors used in finding the stationary distribution of a markov chain?

Tags: markov-chains

In the process of finding the stationary distribution of a markov chain:

$\begin{pmatrix}
\Pi _{1} & \Pi _{2}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
P_{00} & P_{01}\\ 
 P_{10}& P_{11} 
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
\Pi_{1} &\Pi_{2} 
\end{pmatrix}$

i.e $\boldsymbol{\pi} P = \boldsymbol{\pi}$, the stationary distribution is given by the left eigenvectors.

Why are row vectors used?

I am used to the column vector convention, and it's unclear to why this was broken in the resources I found on the stationary distribution. I'm assuming this is just because of how the probability matrix is defined. But why was the probability matrix defined in this way?

Comment: Author's choice. Take transposes to get the other convention.